# A Free Antivirus Software That Asks Before Deletion or Block

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-8, antivirus

I recently used AVG and BitDefender, but both programs block or delete harmful files without asking me.

I want an antivirus program that checks but no matter what, I need to give confirmation before it does anything.

Which one would you suggest for Windows 8.1?

Comment: I'm sure there is an option in both programs to request a confirmation as you desceibed.

Comment: In BitDefender, there is not. I dig into every single setting.

Comment: @cagirici And from Garry's answer you now know that AVG also has that option. Don't make statements in your question that you haven't properly verified.

Comment: Windows 8 comes with Windows Defender built-in with all the features you require including setting what happens when a malware is found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Avast](http://www.avast.com/) (free, Windows) can be [configured](https://superuser.com/a/786653/116475) so that it doesn't block or delete suspicious files:

[image]

FYI: if one day some file ends up in the virus chest, since it's pretty tough to find (as Avast just put in the chest some Matlab file it gave me the opportunity to search for it...):
 [How do I access the avast! Virus Chest?](http://blog.avast.com/2013/11/03/how-do-i-access-the-avast-virus-chest/)

[image]

Comment: Just on a side note, both AVG and Avast! score rather low on AV-Test.org. They may be easier to use, or have a better interface, but I would recommend one with a higher rating. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dsNYl.png)

Answer (score 1):

[AVG Antivirus](http://avg-antivirus-free.soft112.com/) does the same as Avast [described in this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10049/185). It is also free. And personally I find it easier and more intuitive than avast.